# imagescale does not work correctly

Tags: php, image, gd

I'm copying a part of an image using `imagescale`:

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('before.jpg');
$img = imagescale($img, 660, 384);
```

Before:
[image: Before imagescale]

After:
[image: After imagescale]

Using images with less colors works.

Comment: I'd like to know what's happened to $img before this.

Comment: $img = imagecreatefromjpeg('img.jpg');
$img = imagescale($img, 660, 384);

If I remove the second line, the problem doesnt occur.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comments in the PHP documentation propose a solution.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagescale.php

> imageScale has got troubles with scaling images...
>   It can output Segmentation Fault when you want to provide custom $mode argument.
>   How to scale image with interpolation in php gd?
>   Use imagecopyresampled() instead of imagescale().